# Getting rid of file download warning in SAS

Tags: sas

I create SAS output in .rtf format and the File Download warning pops up each time. I need to turn this off for all files that I create. How?

Answer (score 2):

It's under the Recycle Bin's properties. Just right-click Recycle Bin,
properties, and you can turn off the confirmation there.

Comment: This is spooky.

Comment: @mbq, seconded :)

Comment: @ Glen: I did it, but the warning keeps on coming as follows: "your current security settings do not allow this file to be downloaded." Your help will be appreciated. Thanks a lot.